# Checking DB for Empty Records

Tags: java, database, netbeans

This code searches a table on basis of voucher number. In addition to this, I want it to check that if a particular voucher number is present or not and if it is not present then it should tell the user that the specified voucher number doesn't exist. At the moment, when i give a voucher number which is not present in the DB, it doesn't do anything. Suggest some code plz.

```
try {
    String sql = "select item_type as 'Item Type',md_by as 'Made By',"
     + "model as 'Model', selling_price as 'Selling Price',"
     + "selling_date as 'Selling Date', vouch_no as 'Voucher No.',"
     + "vouch_date as 'Voucher Date', record_no as 'Record No.' "
     + "from selling where vouch_no = ?";
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txt_vouchno_s.getText()));
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    Table_s.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}   
catch(SQLException ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex);
}
catch(Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not test for is empty ?

Immediately after your execute statement you can have an if statement. For example

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (!rs.next()){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry your request with ID.1001 not found");
}
```

If a sql resultset is empty then you can not jump to `non empty one` . You are setting a `sql` make a `ps.executeQuery` and look at the result . If result is empty make a new `sql` and so on. Or what do you think `where vouch_no = 1001` means .

You  need two `ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);`

for example

one without sql `where vouch_no = ?`

```
psAll = con.prepareStatement(sqlAll);
psSearch = con.prepareStatement(sqlSearch);
 ...
rsAll = psAll.executeQuery();
Table_s.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rsAll));
```

if your search and find a voucher set Table_s current data record to pointing to that voucher. If not find a voucher set Table_s to the first data record.

Comment: Its good option but i want the app to not only check them but to pass them and jump to the non empty ones.

Comment: what about recursive methods? can't we use them here? I tried to write a recursive method by declaring a global static variable which stored voucher number and every other method in the code uses that voucher num variable but it didn't work.

Comment: @Rehan : You can not use `where vouch_no = ?";` if you want to go through the database records so let it away.

Comment: But then what would be the criteria for searching? i don't want to display all DB records bcz all my other buttons work with vouchers like new button, save button, update button, search button and delete button.

Comment: @Rehan : for update and so you must have `vouchers` . but not for getting a resultset. With your search button you can search but if this number not exists then there is no record with this number !

Comment: For search i have added an exception which tells user that this voucher number doesn't exist but this next and previous buttons' code is making me mad, i want to them to skip empty vouchers and jump to non empty ones.

Comment: @Rehan : So what sense make your question ? : `At the moment, when i give a voucher number which is not present in the DB, it doesn't do anything` ?

Comment: I asked that 2 days ago,  i added the exception handling after that. but that is for searching. For next or previous buttons, i want to tell the user nothing but just to show him/her the next available or previous available voucher.

Comment: @Rehan : we are all human with no special skills to see what you have new changes. So next time please. Show with a `Edit` or `Update` in your Question that you have changed something. You need two con.prepareStatement(sql); Look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom exception (say NoRecordFoundException) and throw it if your result set is empty. This needs to be added in DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(). Then you can add another catch block to see if no record was returned by the database and send appropriate message to the user.